# PDF to Text conversion when uploading to IIS Web App?

Tags: .net, asp.net, pdf, text

I've investigated several C# DLL's and have not found any that work especially well.  My requirements are:

- PDF documents are uploaded via an ASPX page.
- Text needs to be extracted and stored in the DB with the PDF.
- Solution cannot have additional cost for replicating the Web App (so if I *know* it will work, a fixed-fee solution would be considered, but no fee-per-installation).
- Although good conversions are most important, users may wish to upload *many* PDF files at once, so speed is also important.

The downstream process that will consume the text is set up to use [PDFBox](http://incubator.apache.org/pdfbox/), which seems to work well.  But:

- **PDFBox** is written in Java, so I need to launch it as a separate process and retrieve the results (I'm dismissing using it through [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/)).
- By default it reads from disk files, but for both simplicity and speed I'd prefer a *stdin->stdout* filter.  Fixing PDFBox was simple, but getting I/O to a subprocess from C# was tedious.
- I know I could write a new disk to the hard drive, launch PDFBox, wait for it to exit, then read from the hard drive (or its *stdout*), but that seems hackish and would likely be slower.

I'm surprised I cannot find a PDF converter recipe, it seems like a common requirement.  So, could anyone help me with either:

- A canned conversion solution that you use which works *at least* as well as **PDFBox**.
- If using a stdio filter behind IIS is truly a bad idea, an explanation of *why*.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I originally asked how to write binary data to a **Process.StandardInput** (*StreamWriter*) since it only handles character data: the answer is to use **Process.StandardInput.BaseStream** (*Stream*).

In addition, since both pipes might fill up (64KB buffers IIUC), I used the following pattern:

- Spawned a thread to write data, then set a flag,
- Spawned a thread to read all of the return data, then set a flag,
- Loop until both flags are set, calling Thread.Sleep(100).
- Return data read from process.

So other than the hackish aspect of either putting an executable within the WebApp (or requiring a separate install) this seems to work fine -- but I still need to do some abuse testing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the posibility run Process() on your server, you could use XPDF from http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/ One of the utils is PDFtoText that is capapble of extracting text i PDF files, and even maintaining some type of layout.

Back in the old days, I have heard of examples where Adobe search and MS Index service combined could extract text of PDF files as well.